# RegisterStartupScript inside user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, user-controls, registerstartupscript

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChatUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MetamorphismApp.ChatUserControl" %>
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" OnTick="timer1_Tick" Interval="5000">
</asp:Timer>
<div id="divChatWindow" class="clChatWindow">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' class="divHeader" ID="lblChatFriend"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Image ID="imgFriend" runat="server" CssClass="classFriendImage"/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbClose" runat="server" CommandName="Close" CssClass="lbClose"
            OnClick="lbClose_Click">Close</asp:LinkButton></div>
    <div class="chatText" id="idChatText" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSendChat" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpChatMessages">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imageForFriend" runat="server" CssClass="clFriendsImage" ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.jpg?username=" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"fromusername").ToString() %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="chatMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChatMessage" runat="server" Width="142px" CssClass="clChatMessage"
        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendChat" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>'
        OnClick="btnSendChat_Click">Send</asp:LinkButton>
</div>





protected void btnSendChat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = this.FindControl("txtChatMessage") as TextBox;
        string username = lblChatFriend.Text;            
        ucc.InsertMessage(Session["username"].ToString(), username, txt.Text);

        string javaScript = "<script type='text/javascript'>\n" + "CallScroller();\n" + "</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(ChatUserControl), "startUpScript", javaScript, false);
    }
```

btnSendChat function is in a user control code-behind file. CallScroller function doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `RegisterStartupScript` is called when your DOM is loaded, the equivalent with jQuery to:

```
$(function () { ... });
```

Since you are capturing the events from your button inside the `UpdatePanel` using triggers, you are effectively *partial rendering your view* that's why the script registered with `RegisterStartupScript` will never run in this situation

Alternatives:

### React to the Sys.load event

This event is raised every time a page is partial rendered.

Handle the event as follows:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">

    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callScroller() {
            alert("call scroller called");
        }
        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
            if ($get("hidden").getAttribute("value") == "1") {
                callScroller();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Add a `HiddenField` inside your `UpdatePanel.ContentTemplate` to use it as a flag to indicate *when to call the JavaScript function*, without it, your function would get called on every post

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField  runat="server" ID="hidden" Value="0" />
        ....
```

Finally in the code behind *turn on* the flag in the event that best fits your needs:

```
    protected void btnSendChat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.hidden.Value = "1";
    }
```

That's it

Comment: It says Sys.Application.add_load is undefined

Comment: That's related to the `ScriptManager` since I assume you do have one on your page, try adding the `<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" ID="smp" />` to your user control before the script

Comment: Sys is not related with your button. It's an object injected via the `ScriptManager`. mmm Gimme a sec I will test that using a user control

Comment: I had to add Sys.Application.add_load(function () { CallScroller(); }); in document.ready() and now my CallScroller is runnning.. Thanks buddy

Comment: Good catch. Yeah makes sense I tested on a simple page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14450/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-jupaol)